# DjangoアプリケーションをApache2.4で公開する際のエラー（403 Forbidden）についての質問

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache, django

現在、Django-wikiを利用したWEBアプリケーションを作成しています。
まず、Django-wikiのセットアップを行い、開発用サーバを利用してアプリケーションをローカルで開くところまで設定を行いました。
参考記事：
https://django-wiki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

次に、Apacheを利用してセットアップしたアプリケーションを公開する手順を行いました。
参考記事：
https://qiita.com/okoppe8/items/0f67753706cdc11ff1cd

現在、下記のようなエラーが出ており、解決に至ることができませんでした。

ブラウザ：

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at [ipアドレス] Port 80

/var/log/apache2/error.log:
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/[username]/[directory]/[project-name]/[project-name]/wsgi.py, referer: http://ipアドレス/
```

解決のために行ったこと：
アプリケーションの権限について、ディレクトリとwsgi.pyをchmod 777で設定。

django.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /home/username/directory/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

WSGIPythonHome /home/username/directory/venv
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/directory/project/project/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/username/directory/project:/home/username/directory/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages

ServerName hogehoge:80
<Directory /home/username/directory/project/project>
 <Files wsgi.py>
  Require all granted
 </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /home/username/directory/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wiki/static/
<Directory /home/username/directory/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wiki/static>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

OS: VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
PC: ThinkStation P330 Tiny

何か考えうる原因はありませんでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。